# Is there is any Scripting languages is used for mobile application development?

Tags: scripting, java-me

Is there is any Scripting languages is used for mobile application development?

For example java script,vb script is used for web development.Like any scripting language is used for mobile application development along with J2me.

Thanks & Regards,
Sivakumar.J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been successfully using Lua language for MIDP and Blackberry platforms for quite some time. My experience is quite positve and I strongly recommend it.

You could use a CLDC 1.1 port of Lua [Kahlua2](https://github.com/krka/kahlua2)

Do let me know if you have any queries using it.

Edit: I stumbled upon this link [HECL](http://www.hecl.org/), which also looks okay. But the language seems unpolished for my tastes.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, sl4a is good choice with a rich API's included & support for many scripting languages ex: Python, Perl, lua etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but Android has [SL4A (Scripting Layer for Android)](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) which supports lots of scripting languages, among them Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl.

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer thanks for your kind information

Answer (score 0):

Symbian supports [Python](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/Apps%3aPython_Quick_Start) ([with Qt bindings from Nokia](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide)) and [Ruby](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Getting_started_with_Ruby_for_Symbian_OS).

Answer (score -1):

When using standard web technologies to develop web applications, a big constraint is the context in which the application should run. In particular the mobile context is very different from the desktop one even in the design of web applications. Many aspects should be taken into consideration related to hardware and software constraints to which every mobile device is subjected.

It depends onrequirements for your application. For example:

- If as better as possible performance is needed,than a low level language like,Assembler, C or C++, has to be used
- If as better as possible UI is needed,than a high level language, like Java, C# orVisual Basic, has to be used

It is recommended thata prototype of the application and its UIis designed with a high level language.

Also, it is not just a question of some programming language. It is a combination of many-many factors and
one of them is a right set of helperlibraries. An UI library, like QT, could significantly speed up the
development process.

In overall, your application could use any set of different languages and helper libraries.

Comment: "It is a combination of many-many factors (...)". Indeed. And that's why this question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this website. It is better to flag off-topic questions than to answer them!